# Firefox not loading non-secure script when loaded via javascript

Tags: javascript, http, https, cross-domain

I have a secure page on https://www.mysecure.com/page.

I want to load http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.js dynamically via javascript. We are using the same code as google analytics except that we are always loading via http.

This works on all browser except for Firefox. Any ideas why?